# How to fetch records from more than 10 tables and shows the report out of them using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Implementation contains the below things:

1. Fetch `List<id>` from a table. This tables contains the records for which report should be generated. If this table has no records then report won't be generated.
2. Rest of details are inline in the code.

The code looks like below:

```
List<int> totalValidRecords = ; //This comes from a table on the basic of which the report will be generated.

foreach(int id in totalValidRecords)
{
   List<Region> regions= //gets list of record from Region table.

   foreach(Region region in regions)
   {
      List<Country> countries= //gets list of countries from country table based on region.

      foreach(Country country in counties)
      {
        List<State> states = //gets list of states from State table based on country.

        foreach(State state in states)
        {
           List<District> states = //gets list of districts from District table based on state.

           //Other logic which computes and access other rest of dependent tables data.
        }
      }
   }

}
```

The code works perfectly fine but it is taking around 20 seconds to just fetch few records (around 20 records).

This delay of generating report may be because of a lot of `Database` calls is happening but I cannot ignore those calls since these are required to generate the `reports`.

Please let me know if more clarification is required on the questions.

Comment: Why not use joins for that?

Comment: `but it is taking around 20 seconds ` have you timed the various parts of your logic to determine which part is taking the most time. Have you considered breaking this up into smaller logic and hitting the Database and projecting what you need several times, and loading everything into memory?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thanks. Will check and let you know if more input is required.

Comment: @andercruzbr For each of the table there is independent logic in between. But, still will figure out what can I do to optimize to use the `joins`. 
Thanks.

Comment: @bijay-yadav, without know the clauses of queries we cannot help you.
Did you check the database indexes? It can help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your models look like these:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Region : Base
{
}

public class Country : Base
{
    public Region Region {get;set;}
    public int RegionId {get;set;}
}

public class State : Base
{
    public Country Country {get;set;}
    public int CountryId {get;set;}
}

public class District : Base 
{
    public State State {get;set;}
    public int StateId {get;set;}
}
```

Than you can write **single** query via several `join`s;

```
var answer = (from region in db.Regions.Where(x => totalValidRecords.Contains(x.Id))
              join country in db.Country on region.Id equals country.RegionId 
              join state in db.States on country.Id equals state.CountryId 
              join district in db.Districts on state.Id equals district.StateId 
              select new 
              {
                  regionId = region.Id,
                  countryId = country.Id,
                  stateId = state.Id,
                  districtId = district.Id
                  //other fields
              }).ToList();
```